# Understanding what (void) does when placed in front of a function call

Tags: c++

My questions is:

Why is the `(void)` responsible to return a different value? What's exactly happening?

```
struct S {
  int operator,(int) { return 0; }
};
std::cout << (S(), 42) << '\n';           // prints '0'
std::cout << ((void) S(), 42) << '\n';    // prints '42'
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Problem here is that comma operator has been overloaded.

So first line:

```cpp
(S(), 42)
```

Will invoke this custom overload of comma operator, since arguments are `S` and `int` which matches this overload. Note this version always returns `0` value.

In second line:

```
((void) S(), 42)
```

Your custom overload of comma operator doesn't match type passed, since first argument is type of `void` (casting is done). So [build-in version of comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) kicks in. This means that second argument will be returned. That it is why in second line 42 is printed.

Side note:

- Yes C++ allows you to overload comma operator, but it is unusual and quite often treated as a bad practice. In many coding standards it is forbidden.

Comment: Addendum: Always be aware of this danger when writing generic code or macros.

Answer (score 19):

`(void)` is performing [explicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) (to `void`).

For the 1st case `S(), 42`, the `S::operator,` will be invoked on temporary `S` (i.e. `S()`) and return the value `0`.

For the 2nd case, the temporary `S` is converted to `void` explicitly, so for `(void) S(), 42` the [built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) will be invoked instead, as the effect the 2nd operand `42` will be returned by comma operator and then printed out. (The 1st operand `(void) S()` is evaluated firstly and the result is discarded.)

> The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand

Answer (score 17):

The important thing to note in the second statement is that the cast has **higher precedence** over the comma operator `,`. This means that the expression  `((void) S(), 42)` is actually grouped as(or equivalent to writing) `(((void) S()), 42)` due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Thus in the second case, the temporary `S()` is first cast to `void` so that the resulting type is `void`. Now, since the custom overloaded `S::operator,(int)` is **no longer viable**(as it takes argument of type `S` and `int`), the built in `operator,` will be used with operands of type `void`(that was returned from the cast you used) and `42` and it will return the rightmost operand `42`. Hence the second statement print `42`.